# Include empty factor levels in tally with tidyr and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, levels, tally

a question as a learn dplyr and its ilk.

I am calculating a tally and a relative frequency of a factor conditioned on two other variables in a df. For instance:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
set.seed(3457)
pct <- function(x) {x/sum(x)}
foo <- data.frame(x = rep(seq(1:3),20),
                  y = rep(rep(c("a","b"),each=3),10),
                  z = LETTERS[floor(runif(60, 1,5))])
bar <- foo %>%
group_by(x, y, z) %>%
tally %>%
mutate(freq = (n / sum(n)) * 100)
head(bar)
```

I'd like the output, `bar`, to include all the levels of `foo$z`. I.e., there are no cases of `C` here:

```
subset(bar, x==2 & y=="a")
```

How can I have `bar` tally the missing levels so I get:

```
subset(bar, x==2 & y=="a",select = n)
```

to return 4, 5, 0, 1 (and `select = freq` to give 40, 50, 0, 10)?

Many thanks.

Edit: Ran with the seed set!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr`

```
bar1 <- bar %>%
           complete(z, nesting(x, y), fill = list(n = 0, freq = 0))%>%
           select_(.dots = names(bar))
filter(bar1, x==2 & y=="a")   
#      x      y      z     n  freq
#   <int> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     2      a      A     4    40
#2     2      a      B     5    50
#3     2      a      C     0     0
#4     2      a      D     1    10
```